# Are Spring-Boot-Test @MockBeans supposed to qualify for @ConditionalOnBean conditions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I have a java `@Configuration` class with a `FOO @Bean` annotated with `@ConditionalOnBean(BAR.class).` As I expect this bean to be or not provided by the importer project, it's not present anywhere in my project.

In my integration test, I mock `Bar.class` by means of `@MockBeans`. But for some reason Spring-Boot -debug tells me it did not found it so my conditional bean has not been loaded.

I'm almost sure this situation has worked properly in the past, but did I configure anything extra? I can't manage to make it work

P.S> I discovered that manually re-registering the @Bean in the same @Configuration as the conditional does not see it neither! Is there any known bug related to his?

Autoreply: The culprit in this case is

> You need to be very careful about the order that bean definitions are
>   added as these conditions are evaluated based on what has been
>   processed so far. For this reason, we recommend only using
>   @ConditionalOnBean and @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations on
>   auto-configuration classes (since these are guaranteed to load after
>   any user-defined beans definitions have been added).

P.S2> I realized Bar.class is an interface but I don't see why shouldn't it work as long as an implementation is present

**P.S3> I found out that the MockitoTestExecutionListener is executed after the OnBeanCondition class. This seems my problem totally.**

Comment: It is not clear, could you please clarify "As I expect this bean to be or not provided by the importer project, it's not present anywhere in my project."

Comment: @fg78nc I'm doing an starter (hence the `@ConditionalOnBean`), so depending on the presence or not of BAR @Bean, I'll configure FOO or not.  In the context of Boot, is there any name for what I am calling "importer"?

Comment: Regardless of whether they are *currently* supposed to, it makes complete sense to me that if I provide an `@MockBean` in my test, it should trigger autoconfiguration conditions. I suggest filing a bug against BOOT describing this case.

Comment: I extended the question with 2 considerations

Comment: Is `@ConditionalOnBean` in an auto configuration class?

Comment: its intended to be, currently is just a plain configuration

Comment: "As I expect this bean to be or not provided by the importer project, it's not present anywhere in my project." That's actually wrong. Please review the javadoc of `@ConditionalOnBean`. It's only meant to be used in auto-configuration.

Comment: I pasted the responses from Github you gave me and Ill close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This and this explain why it is not possible:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9624 and
- https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot?at=59536ea74bcd78af56538629